# Node.js Express haml not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, haml, express

My repo for this problem is at: https://github.com/okor/express_bad_haml

The problem is that I can get the app to render the layout correctly, or the page, but not both. Resulting in this: http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7170/6818833785_80bcc2b2fe_z.jpg

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I had previously set 
`app.set("view options", {layout: true});` 
I changed that setting to 
`app.set("view options", {layout: false});`
And that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your browser is trying to render the output as plain text. Try to forcing the output header to text/html:

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
```

Comment: Well, it's definitely plain text. But it's not a browser issue. The browser (Chrome OSx) reports html. I did however try your tip, but no luck.